# sed mass replace CSS styles via terminal

Tags: regex, linux, sed, terminal, find

I want to replace all instances of `font-family: ([A-Za-z ,"]+){1};` with `font-family: Verdana` using `sed`.  In the past, the following command has worked for *simple* search & replace:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/needle/replace/' {} \;
```

However, I tried the following regex with no success:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/(font\-family:){1}([\"A-Za-z, ]+){1}(;){1}/font\-family: Verdana;/' {} \;
```

I'm on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6.  Additionally, the first command seems to only work on the first instance in any given file, which means I have to rerun the command until every instance gets replaced... can I improve the command to work on all instances of all files?

Comment: Did you try using `g` option for global replacements. `sed 's/needle/replace/g'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, an explanation of why yours doesn't work.  You need to escape all of your parentheses, square brackets, and the `+`, so the following should work:

```
sed -i 's/\(font\-family:\)\{1\}\(["A-Za-z, ]\+\)\{1\}\(;\)\{1\}/font-family: Verdana;/'
```

Fortunately you can add the `-r` switch to prevent the need for all of that escaping, but you can also simplify your current expression quite a bit.  You do not need to put every section into a capturing group, and adding `{1}` to every group is redundant (that is basically the default).  So you could reduce it to:

```
sed -ri 's/font-family:["A-Za-z, ]+;/font-family: Verdana;/g'
```

Note the added `g` option for global replacement, since you want this for every occurrence.

All together:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -ri 's/font-family:["A-Za-z, ]+;/font-family: Verdana;/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, you need `-r` in your sed, since you used `+`

see the test below:

```
kent$  echo "oldstring_0000"|sed 's/[0]+/newstring/'
oldstring_0000

nothing happened.

now with -r:

kent$  echo "oldstring_0000"|sed -r 's/[0]+/newstring/'
oldstring_newstring
```

also if you want to replace all, you need 'g' like 's/a/b/g'

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
sed -i 's/\(font-family:\) \(.*[^;]\)\(;.*\)/\1 Verdana\3/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your font-family expresion: `font-family: ([A-Za-z ,"]+){1};`  Are those matching parens and you're looking for `{1}` exactly one match?

Your regex is just complicated enough that I'd switch from `sed` to `perl -pi`:

```
find ./ -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/font-family:[\"A-Za-z, ]+;/font-family: Verdana;/g' {} \;
```